# What authoritative reference confirms that DWV vents discharge gases as well as admit air?

Tags: plumbing

Can someone cite an authoritative reference which states that a waste vent (*e.g. one that goes out through the attic roof*) discharges potentially noxious sewer gases?

I have always accepted this as a truism but someone has challenged me to back up my opinion by referencing an authority. They're saying that the traps prevent sewer gases from entering and that the vents are only to equalize the air pressure and make sure the water in the traps doesn't get drawn out.

I pointed out that code requires the vents not to be located anywhere near windows but that did not suffice.

*By "authoritative reference" I mean some sort of engineering handbook, not a Wikipedia article or plumbing forum or even an article in a homebuilding magazine.*

Comment: My nose is fairly authoritative. Go up on your roof and have a sniff for yourself. Methane is a byproduct of the decomposition of organic matter. Heck, you emit a fair bit yourself. What more evidence do you need? It can only come out of the plumbing in one direction--the other end is plugged with liquid.

Comment: And how is that methane getting past the traps? Under what circumstances does that occur (if we set aside *inadequately sized* venting)?

Comment: There are no traps on vents. There are traps on drains.

Comment: I know that. But the traps stand between the vent and the waste pipe to the sewer.

Comment: What makes you think this someone will accept some other reference, if they won't accept Wikipedia, or a plumber, or a homebuilder?

Comment: I retract my statement above. The trap stands between the waste pipe and the room in which the fixture is located.

Comment: Isn't the column of air in the main stack enough to keep the sewer gases from rising?

Comment: Not if said column is -12F and drops below the warm stink below. That's basic convection.

Comment: Also, see [Bernoulli's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle), which tends to mix and scavenge gas as breezes pass by.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the gas is being _generated_ down there. As I said... decomposition. This causes a buildup of positive pressure.

Comment: Vents  **DO/CAN** discharge potentially noxious sewer gases to the outside of the structure. Vents **DO** prevent a vacuum  from forming that would effect drainage.  Traps **DO** prevent sewer gases, in drain lines and vents, from entering the living space. *Taken from the authoritative guide to common sense by Alaska Man*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your knucklehead acquaintance can just plug their vents for all the evidence they need. Then they can write a paper and have it reviewed by peers.

Comment: I found good explanations of convection inside a cylinder here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235079/why-does-hot-air-rise-in-a-column-instead-of-cold-air-pressing-down

Comment: Convection probably isn't even the primary driver. Gas generation in the lower reaches of the system builds pressure. Convection probably provides mixing up high, but that's secondary.

Comment: Just look up cases where traps dried up and the methane explosion damaged the home. This is not about home improvement and obviously the op can not understand the 1” of water that Alaska man provided another vote to close and a rare down vote

Comment: @Ed Beal: you have misunderstood the question. The question assumes traps are in working order.  And the question is indeed about home improvement. The person I was speaking with has a vent that discharges in the *attic*. Does not penetrate the roof.

Comment: Ed isn't claiming that your question is about dried-out traps. Ed is using the thought experiment of "imagine the trap dries up" to explain that yes, there is sewer gas in the vent system, and that yes, it has to go somewhere, and that yes, that somewhere is typically out the top of the stack.

Comment: Mr blint, you should have stated that as vents are not allowed inside the structure with the exception of AAV’s they allow air in but no gas to escape. Your question and comments don’t back what you actually did ask.

Comment: @Doug Deden:The question was whether there is an authority I could refer to which explicitly states that sewer gases can exit the *vents above the roof*, not whether these gases can exit through dried out traps. I'm not the skeptic here, as I said, but someone else was, who believed that their attic vent was safe.

Comment: Then I'll ask again: What makes you think this someone will accept some other reference, if they won't accept Wikipedia, or a plumber, or code, or a homebuilder? If this someone will accept that the gas can escape a dried-out trap, it follows that they should accept that the gas can escape the top of the vent. There's no third option.

Answer (score 3):

> What authoritative reference confirms that DWV vents discharge gases
> as well as admit air?

"*901.2 Trap seal protection.  The plumbing system shall be provided with a system of vent piping that will permit the **admission or emission** of air so that  the seal of any fixture trap shall not be subjected to a pressure differential of more than 1 inch of water column. (249 Pa)*".

[2018 International Plumbing Code (IPC), chapter 9, Vents](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-9-vents)

[Inspectapedia, Vents](https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/Plumbing-Vent-Distance-Codes.php).

Comment: I was reading through various plumbing codes but couldn't find references to discharge of sewer gases out the vent, except indirectly through limitations on where main vent pipes can be located as they exit a building.  But I do accept that convection cells could allow sewer gases to rise up the main stack.

Comment: @mrblint, Just look at the definition of a venting system: "...to provide flow of air to or from a drainage system...".

Comment: These plumbers seems to have iron noses, accepting as "air"  substances that other mere mortals would not,.

Answer (score 0):

You are both in part correct.

Here is the definition of a venting system from my local plumbing code:

> *Venting system means an assembly of pipes and fittings that **connects a drainage system with outside air for circulation of air** and the protection of trap seals in the drainage system.* – British
> Columbia Plumbing Code

So the purpose of the vent is to protect the trap seal, which if maintained will prevent sewer gas from entering the building. The vent achieves this by allowing air/gas to move freely into and out of the drainage system. To allow this free air movement, vents provide a direct passage way from the drainage system to the outside air. Because vent are directly connected to the drainage system and will by definition allow free air movement into and out of the drainage system, they will allow sewer gases to exit and that is why there are regulations on where vents can terminate.

Here's the definition from the [2018 International Plumbing Code](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-2-definitions):

> VENT SYSTEM. A pipe or pipes installed to provide a **flow of air to or
> from a drainage system**, or to provide a circulation of air within such
> system to protect trap seals from siphonage and backpressure.

By definition, a venting system will allow air/gas to **enter *or exit*** the drainage system.

Comment: Repeating the stated purpose of a vent doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I was elaborating (or trying to) on the "circulation of air" requirement of a venting system. By the definition, air/gas within the drainage system must be able to move freely into and out of the drainage system.

Comment: Yep. That's undisputed. The question asks for an authorities reference. You've offered conjecture. Though well-founded throughout history, it doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: I don't think you will find a code that explicitly states it. I did provide a definition from a code that states that the vent provides circulation of air from within the drainage system and outside.